# What's the Fourier transform of $\delta_{x-y^2}$

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

What's the Fourier transform of $\delta_{x-y^2}$?

---

Here we have $\displaystyle \delta_{x-y^2}(\varphi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi(y^2,y)\, dy$, where $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$. I already know that $\hat{\delta}= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}$, but I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Can you define the distribution $\delta_{x-y^2}$

Comment: $\delta_{x-y^2} (\varphi) = \int_R \varphi(y^2,y) \,dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure $\langle T,\varphi\rangle = \int_\Bbb{R} \varphi(y^2,y) \,dy$ is the distribution you are interested in, not the arc-length parametrization? If so then let

$$\langle T_h,\varphi\rangle = \int_\Bbb{R} e^{-hy^2}\varphi(y^2,y) \,dy$$
So that $$\widehat{T}(u,v)=\lim_{h\to0}\widehat{T}_h(u,v)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1\pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-h y^2} e^{-i (uy^2+vy)} dy$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1\pi e^{-\frac{v^2}{4(h+i u)}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(h+i u)(y+\frac{i v}{2(h+i u)})^2} dy=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1\pi e^{-\frac{v^2}{4(h+i u)}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(h+i u)y^2} dy$$
(Cauchy integral formula)
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-\frac{ v^2}{4(h+i u)}}}{\pi (h+i u)^{1/2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2} dy=\frac{e^{-\frac{ v^2}{4i u}}}{\pi (i u)^{1/2}} \sqrt{\pi}$$
where around $u=0$ the last step is convergence in $L^1_{loc}$ sense.